# Mokito unit test over Map.Entry

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

I have searched everywhere but couldn't find the answer.

Please any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my class

```
@Component
public class Lookup {

    protected String getDesc(String item, Map<String,String> map) {
        String desc = null;
        for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry: map.entrySet()){
            if(entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(item) {
                desc = entry.getValue();
            }
        }
        return desc;
    }
}
```

Here is my test class
If I remove the check on EntrySet, it works but doesn't covered the if statement

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class LookupTest {

    @InjectMocks Lookup lookup;

    @Test
    public void testLookup_Item() {

        String item = "item_1";
        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        map.put("item_1", "Description");
    
        when(map.entrySet().contains(item)).thenReturn(true);  //this doesn't work
    
        String desc = lookup.getDesc(item, map);
        assertEquals("Description", desc);
    }
}
```

Comment: Write when part after assertEquals

Comment: Change public void testLookup_Item() to public boolean  testLookup_Item()

Comment: You cannot assign new behaviour with when/then on actual classes. This needs to be done on a Mock or a Spy. Is there a reason you wish to mock this method instead of having it call the actual contains method?

Comment: The phrase „If I remove the check on EntrySet, it works but doesn't covered the if statement” is unclear. 1. There is no check on EntrySet in your code. 2. It is unclear how you measure coverage. 3. As @Rick said, you need a spy or a mock to assign new behaviour. 4. That is NOT a suggestion to mock HasHMap or Map.Entry. You mock collaborators of a class, not the core of functionality under test.